# A robot moves on 2-Dimensional grid. It starts out at (0,0) and is allowed to move in any of these four ways:

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A robot moves on 2-Dimensional grid. It starts out at (0,0) and is allowed to move in any of these four ways:
1. (+2,-1)
2. (-2,+1)
3. (+1,+3)
4. (-1,-3)
Prove that this robot can never reach position (1,1)

Comment: Try experimenting. Use a sheet of quad paper (paper with squares). Mark $(0,0)$ and each point the robot can reach. You should quickly see a parallelogram tiling similar to [this](http://www.math.washington.edu/~king/coursedir/m444a03/lab/lab-11-21_files/Image8.gif) (search Google Images for parallelogram tiling if link is broken). The desired destination is in the interior of one of the parallelograms, while the points the robot can reach, are the vertices of the parallelograms. While this is not a rigorous proof, it will help your intuition about the span of two linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to find an invariant. If

$$\langle x,y\rangle\in\{\langle 2,-1\rangle,\langle -2,1\rangle,\langle 1,3\rangle,\langle -1,-3\rangle\}\;,\tag{1}$$

then $3x-y\equiv0\pmod7$.

For any position $\langle a,b\rangle$, let $r(a,b)=(3a-b)\bmod7$, the remainder when $3a-b$ is divided by $7$. If $\langle x,y\rangle$ is one of the legal moves in $(1)$, then

$$\begin{align*}
r(a+x,b+y)&=\big(3(a+x)-(b+y)\big)\bmod7\\
&=\big((3a-b)+(3x-y)\big)\bmod7\\
&=(3a-b)\bmod7\\
&=r(a,b)\;,
\end{align*}$$

since $(3x-y)\bmod7=0$.

In particular, if the robot starts at $\langle 0,0\rangle$, then $r(a,b)=r(0,0)=0$ for each position $\langle a,b\rangle$ that the robot can reach. However, $r(1,1)=2$, so the robot cannot reach $\langle 1,1\rangle$.

Comment: How do you get 3x−y≡0(mod7) in the beginnning ?

Comment: @Tom: Experience, some playing around, and a little luck. In all honesty, in this problem the approach taken by **Matthias** will probably get you the result at least as quickly unless you've had some experience with this sort of problem.

Answer (score 2):

For simplisity lets say the robot moves $i\in\mathbb Z$ steps in direction $\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $j\in\mathbb Z$ steps in direction $\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}$.

So you get
$$i\cdot\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\end{pmatrix}+j\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

If you want to get your first component to be $1$ you get the constraint
$$j=1-2i$$
But if you want at the same time that your second component should be $1$ you get the additional constraint
$$i=-1+3j=-1+3(1-2i)=2-6i$$

So you get $7i=2$ and thus $i=\frac27$ which is no integer number. This leads to the contradiction that we assumed $i\in\mathbb Z$.
Thus there is no way to reach point $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

PS. Hope there are not that many calculation errors.