# A linearly independent matrix doesn't have integer solution for some vector x

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The whole question was too big for the title:

> If a linearly independent matrix doesn't have an integer solution for some vector $x$, then can adding a linearly dependent vector to the matrix produce an integer solution?

This question arose from the [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154525/a-robot-moves-on-2-dimensional-grid-it-starts-out-at-0-0-and-is-allowed-to-mo). **Answer $2$** reduced the problem to two linearly linearly independent vectors, where as original problem consisted of $4$ vectors, this seems to imply that you can just "discard" linearly dependent vectors (as they wouldn't produce integer solutions), but I'm not seeing why? Apologies if the question is very trivial.

For example: $$i\cdot\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\end{pmatrix}+j\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
This equation has no solutions in $\mathbb Z$.
How do I know for sure that $$i\cdot\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\end{pmatrix}+j\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix} + k\cdot\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
for some $a,b \in \mathbb Z$  won't have a solution in $\mathbb Z$ as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does have a solution.  $i=j=k=1$ and $${a \choose b} = {-2 \choose -1}$$.

Comment: Haha, of course it does!  I seem to have misunderstood the solution provided in the thread, the author didn't "discard" the vectors as I thought he did. Upon further look, it now makes sense.